# Temp modification of NHibernate Entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is there a way I can tell Nhibernate to ignore any future changes on a set of objects retrieved using it?

```
public ReturnedObject DoIt()
{
    List<MySuperDuperObject> awesomes = repository.GetMyAwesomenesObjects();
    var sp = new SuperParent();
    BusinessObjectWithoutNHibernateAccess.ProcessThese(i, awesomes,sp)
    repository.save(sp);
    return i;
}

public ReturnedObject FakeIt()
{
    List<MySuperDuperObject> awesomes = repository.GetMyAwesomenesObjects();
    var sp = new SuperParent();
    // should something go here to tell NHibernate to ignore changes to awesomes and sp?
    return BusinessObjectWithoutNHibernateAccess.ProcessThese(awesomes,sp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evict the objects from the session. See the method `ISession.Evict`.

Comment: the signature only takes object.... will this work on the entire collection or... is a loop required?  Does it nest down the entire object's graph or just the particular object?

Comment: to anyone reading this question.... no loop is required when you evict an item all of it's collections are evicted as well.